# message: "Could not upload" | Angular Uploading Image With Post

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, multipartform-data, angular8

I am uploading image selected with input tag to an api
Server Response - `{status: false, message: "Could not upload"}`
, 
component.html -

```
 <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" id="upload" style="display:none" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
```

Component.ts

```
fileChange(event): void {
  const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
  if (fileList.length > 0) {
      const file = fileList[0];

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file, file.name);
      const headers = new Headers();

      this.http.post(SERVER_URL, formData).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res)
        }
      )
  }
}
```

I am using Interceptor for auth. All other apis with formdata working properly, I m not sure why its not working.

Comment: We used to have similar problems recently. If you see what you send in your console, you will know if the file data is appended to the request or not. In our case we have had 2 interceptors breaking the query – first one used to replace the "Content-type" header and the second one used to break the body. So if you are sure, your backend works properly, you may search the problem in the interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to append the method as well, and test without the filename, like this:

```
this.formData.append('_method', 'POST');
this.formData.append('file', file);
```

It works for me... Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried adding `this.formData.append('_method', 'POST');
this.formData.append('file', file);` Same response, Its working for me in other places where m uploading text, Looks like m missing something here.

Comment: What if you try doing this **event.target.files[0];** instead of creating a **FileList**?

Comment: this.formData.append('_method', 'POST');
this.formData.append('file', file); worked for me thanks , It was error with backend.